# How to fix undefined method error in rails app using has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get an error when I try to visit the below url in my rails app.

```
http://localhost:3000/origtexts/1/reviews/new
```

routes.rb

```
resources :origtexts do
  resources :reviews
end
```

It passes the param of the review (1) correctly but I the error I get is undefined method `review' for the line in ReviewsController#new.

reviews_controller.rb

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :find_origtext
    before_filter :find_review, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
        @review = @origtext.review.build
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
        @review = @origtext.reviews.build(params[:review])
        if @review.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Review has been created'
            redirect_to [@origtext, @review]
        else
            flash[:alert] = 'Review has not been created'
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end


    private
    def find_origtext
        @origtext = Origtext.find(params[:origtext_id])
    end

    def find_review
        @review = @origtext.reviews.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `review` to `reviews` in this line

```
@review = @origtext.review.build
```

To

```
@review = @origtext.reviews.build
```